# capture alert box selection android

Tags: android, dialog

I have a button in android which on clicking produces an alert box. But i don't know how to capture the selected value from the alert box. My code is

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

String[] items = new String[] {"name", "doc", "age"};
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);

btn.setText("Select One");

 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
              .setTitle("Select Airport")
              .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                  dialog.dismiss();
                }
              }).create().show();

        }

    });
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: m not getting...whats your actual problem is ..

Comment: @NiravBhandari Initially my button has some value say colour red. if i want to change the value of red , i click on the button and i am provided with a range of other colours that i can select. I want to change the value of the button to the value that i selected from the alert box.!

Comment: Are you using adapter in listView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code

```
int which
```

argument of `onClick` event of `AlertDialog` returns the number of position of the item that is selected.

For checking you just `Toast` a message when you select any item from `AlertDialog`

Code :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
          .setTitle("Select Airport")
          .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

              Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"You Selected : "+items[which],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              dialog.dismiss();
            }
          }).create().show();

    }

});
```

You can refer [Android's Official Guide On Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)  for more information about Dialogs in Android